# Laptop recommendation for 2 monitors at home, drawing, programming and occasionally gaming

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, gaming, development, thunderbolt

Lately I have been running in problem with my recent laptop and i have decided to buy a new one.

I have been looking for a laptop to answer the following things:

1. Powerful CPU (Kaby Lake i7 with Dual Core, even Quad if the price is not high)
2. 8GB Ram minimum and the ability to extend up to 16 gb if needed in the future..
3. Small in size (13' inch) and weight
4. Battery Life pretty long for at least 7 hours
5. 512GB of SSD
6. Ability to use a Pen with the ActivePen support(TouchScreen + 360 degree flip)
7. Thunderbolt ports to support : 2 monitors, external GPU, external Keyboard and mouse
8. Has decent ability to play games like Dota2, League of Legends and Overwatch

My current laptop is Lenovo Y50 and I didn't really liked it because of its weight and the design, the laptop i had before was HP envy(don't really remember the model number) which was pretty strong with DualCore and 1.5Kg in weight.

The HP was pretty great but water was poured on him by accident.

My main issue with the requests of the laptop was the price.

The laptops that were answering these categories but not fully were HP Spectre x360(2017 edition) and Microsoft Surface 4, Dell XPS 13, Lenovo Yoga 710/910. Each laptop had something missing except for the latest HP Spectre x360 but the price was very high.

Now after all this summary, I saw yesterday that a new laptop has emerged from Lenvovo. The Lenovo Yoga 720 which actually does answer my expectations BUT!

The thing I'm afraid now are the following topics:

1. I know that i can connect an external GPU for example GeForce GTX 1080, but what about it's preformance through the Thunderbolt, does it degrade? does anything else been done on the CPU(not the GPU processing unit) itself or the iGPU?
2. I want to connect to 1 of the Thunderbolt ports a peripheral which will give me 2 DisplayPorts/Hdmi so I could connect the laptops to 2 monitors at home with keyboard and mouse to work. When I'm not i just disconnect the laptop from the connections and go to College or work. but doesn't 2 monitors will be really hard on the Intel Iris 620? I mean wouldn't the 2 monitors make it degrade or die faster or something like that?

Worth saying that I don't really want to purchase a desktop pc(not a laptop) because of the features i noted at the beginning.

If you have any other options you can recommend instead the Lenovo Yoga 720 i would like to hear.

More over, I heared the Lenovo has Yoga 720 15 inch model which has GTX 1050 dedicated GPU which can be at help at my case.
But if the solutions i suggested are better i will go with the 13 inch model with anyone opinion that is on board with the 13 model :)

Thank you and sorry for the long post